# Compile time error using Zurb Foundation 6 with Angular 5: error TS2339: Property 'Reveal' does not exist on type 'FoundationStatic'

Tags: angular, typescript, zurb-foundation

In my component I am initializing foundation

```
ngOnInit() {
  $(document).foundation();
}
```

And I have a click handlers for opening and closing my modal

```
openOtherIncomeSelect(category) {
  let modal = new Foundation.Reveal($('#'+category));
  modal.open();
}

closeOtherIncomeModal(category, action) {
  let modal = new Foundation.Reveal($('#'+category));
  modal.close();
  $('.reveal-overlay').remove();
 }
```

Everything works very well but I get a compile time error for each of the two references to Foundation.Reveal()

```
error TS2339: Property 'Reveal' does not exist on type 'FoundationStatic'.
```

Comment: I have @types/foundation installed and I've tried installing @types/foundation-sites and the error persists.

I also tried using the deprecated typings but that only results in Foundation not found errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a direct solution to my problem, I've found an acceptable workaround. My updated and working handlers for opening modals in ts are

```
openOtherIncomeSelect(category) {

  if (this.openedModals.indexOf(category) === -1) {
    this.openedModals.push(category);
    $('#'+category).foundation();
  }

  let modalElement = $('#'+category);
  modalElement.foundation('open');

}

closeOtherIncomeModal(category, action) {
  let modalElement = $('#'+category);
  modalElement.foundation('close');
 }
```

Note that with this approach I need to initialize foundation on each modal element (I have several on this page) before I can manipulate it. Since I get a JS error if I initialize foundation on the same element twice, I'm keeping track of which elements have been initialized in an array. This way users can open the same modal twice without problems.

Comment: Note that if someone adds an answer with how to use Foundation.Reveal, I'll happily accept that answer